# Rewrite .php to .aff and treat .aff as php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

On my website I have an affiliates/ folder.

Inside that I have showgames.php

I want to be able to access the file as www.website.com/affiliates/showgames.aff

Inside affiliates folder,I placed this .htaccess

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .aff
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1.aff [R=permanent]
```

For some reasons , it doesnt work .

Comment: It doesn't work because you are rewriting it to forward the request to their .aff counterparts. But for this to work you have to modify the apache configuration to register other extensions for the PHP interpreter as well.

Comment: why dont you do it like this: `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.aff(.+)$ $1.php?$2 [L]`

Comment: does apache have a registered .aff extension ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand what rewriting is.

You say you have a `/affiliates/showgames.php` page that you want to be accessible as `/affiliates/showgames.aff`. This means the **second** must be internally rewritten to the **first** when it's requested, not the other way around.

This also means that you do not need to interpret `.aff` files as PHP scripts. Just do this in `affiliates`' .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.aff$ $1.php [QSA]
```

Comment: not working ... what does Q ,S and A mean ? I tried to add only that line in affiliates htaccess and didnt work

Comment: See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html QSA means "query string append". If it didn't work, perhaps you need `RewriteEngine on`. Otherwise, you have to be more specific than "didn't work"

Comment: I got it working finally , after adding 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.aff$ $1.php [QSA]

Thx